# Getting parse / syntax error and can not figure out why

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){ 
    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $password = $_POST['password']; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM main_member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'"; 
    require_once('connect.php'); 
    sql $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
    $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  
    if(isset($check));
    { 
        echo "success"; 
    }else{ 
        echo "Gagal"; 
    } 
    mysqli_close($con); 
}
?>
```

it says parse error syntax error, unexpected $result T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\login.php on line 7, please help me guys i really appreciate it

Comment: Why is `sql` before `$result`?

Comment: i dont know, i just copied it from someone's project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have error in this line

```
sql $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

change this to

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

change this line

```
if(isset($check));
```

to

```
if(isset($check))
```

Comment: wow thanks man, it worked but another error appears and it say Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\login.php on line 12,, can you help me again? please >_<

Comment: if(isset($check)) no need of semi colon

Comment: omg it works,, thanks man i'm so happy right now*tears